# catching the 10th character properly with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to automatically convert a phone number typed in an input box to (xxx) xxx-xxxx format where x is the phone number someone types in. I can actually get it working when the input box loses focus but I'm trying to also change it once the 10th character is typed in the input. It's working but not until you click the 11th character and I cannot figure out why.

```
<input type="tel" class='tel' placeholder="(555) 555-1212" maxlength=10>
<div class="result"></div>

var convert_phone = function () {
    var phone_num = $('.tel').val();
    var phone_check = phone_num.search(/^\(?\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}$/);

    if (phone_check == 0) {
        var parts = phone_num.match(/^\(?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/);
        $('.tel').val('('+parts[1]+') '+parts[2]+'-'+parts[3]);
    }
}

$('.tel').on('keypress', function () {
    var current_val = $(this).val().length;

    $('.result').text(current_val);
    if (current_val == 10) {
        convert_phone();
    }
})

$('.tel').on('blur', function() {
    convert_phone();
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s6frnp2k/3/
The result div is just there to show click value and isn't needed for the final version.

Comment: change 'keypress' to 'keyup', fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s6frnp2k/4/

Comment: Since this in an `input` element, why not listen for the `input` event instead of keyboard presses? But, even then you will have some issues, since you are not handling the case of someone hitting delete or backspace. Moreover, the new length of your phone number will exceed the `maxlength` of 10 with the added characters

Comment: @wlh I started down that path and realized the same thing.